# Export the man page in text form

Tags: linux, command, output, export, manpage

If I output in a small window, man will automatically do a line break for the text.
How do I get the man to not automatically change lines on output?
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWdHj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified man's configuration

```
$ export MANWIDTH=9999999
```